# Django forms: Changing help_text dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

Is this even possible?

So let's say that I have two forms, one inherits from the other because they have similar fields with the same validation.  But the only difference is they have different help text.  How could I have two different help text on these forms?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
class A(Form):
  f = CharField(help_text='sth')


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['f'].help_text = 'changed'
```

Comment: It's preferable to call `super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` instead of `A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, but yes, that will work.

Comment: I've fixed this. I never know, which I should use.